# Как при переходе по ссылки на страницу(#accordeon) сделать так что бы не только переходил к блоку но еще открывал его автоматический?

Tags: javascript, html, css

При выборе айди в адресной строке раскрыть блок.
Получается есть 10 блоков аккордеонов на одной странице, как при переходе с другого сайта с используемым **айди#block1** сделать так чтобы не только направляло на этот аккордеон а так же открывало его?

Comment: при загрузке странице проверьте наличие `#` в URL, если есть, проверьте есть ли у вас аккордеоны с таким ID, и если найдете, то раскройте.

Comment: вы бы еще помогли бы мне с названием функции или примером) ссылкой) было бы замечательно

Comment: у вас бутстрап с jquery или другое что то?

Answer (score 0):

Ану так попробуйте

```
function openAccordeon(){
    if(location.hash.length <= 1)return;
    var el = document.querySelector(location.hash);
    if(!el)return;

    if (el.classList.contains("collapsed")) {
        el.classList.remove("collapsed");
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", openAccordeon);
window.addEventListener("hashchange", openAccordeon);
```

Answer (score -1):

Добавь в ссылку атрибуты id и onclick. В id запиши тот id, который тебе нужно будет открыть. По умолчанию в CSS элемент скрыт. JS его открывает.

`<a id="block1" href="#block1" onclick="changeDiv(this.id)">Link</a>`

```
function changeDiv(divID) {
    var ifclosed = document.getElementById(divID).style.display;

    if (ifclosed==='' || ifclosed==='none') {
        document.getElementById(divID).style.display = "block"; // show body div tag
}
```

Comment: а если вот с сайта А на сайт Б переходят по ссылке http://siteB.kz#block1 
Он откроется сразу этот аккордеон с айди Блок1?

Comment: Наверное нет, этого уже не знаю